# How to use MERGE (or something else) in neo4j to create new nodes and relationships based on info in labels in other relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So basically I'm trying to create relationships in a network, based on information that is in other relationships. I've added an example to demonstrate what I'd like to achieve.

In this example I'm tracking users who have twitter accounts. There are two types of nodes:

1. `User` which contains the label `user_id` (and some other stuff), generally has nothing to do with the twitter id
2. `Social` which represents a social network (for example Twitter if the `name` label is 'twitter').

On top of that there are two types of relationships:

1. `ACCOUNT` which connects `User` to `Social` to denote whether someone has an account, this relationship also has the label `name` to represent the specific ID or name on that social network
2. `FOLLOWS` which can connect one `User` (`u1`) to another `User` (`u2`) if `u1` follows `u2` on Twitter.

The following three lines create three users with `user_id` 1 through 3 who all have a Twitter account, including the specific twitter id.

```
MERGE (u:User {user_id:'1', other_stuff:'...'}) MERGE (s:Social {name:'twitter'}) MERGE (u)-[:ACCOUNT {name:1111}]->(s)
MERGE (u:User {user_id:'2', other_stuff:'...'}) MERGE (s:Social {name:'twitter'}) MERGE (u)-[:ACCOUNT {name:2222}]->(s)
MERGE (u:User {user_id:'3', other_stuff:'...'}) MERGE (s:Social {name:'twitter'}) MERGE (u)-[:ACCOUNT {name:3333}]->(s)
```

So now I have a new piece of information: The person with twitter id `1111` follows another person with twitter id `5555`.

So what has to happen:

1. Find the user connected to Twitter with id `1111` (This one always exists)
2. See if there is a user connected to Twitter who has an account with id `5555`. If there's none then create a new one, set the Twitter relationship and set a `user_id` label on the node
3. Set a `FOLLOWS` relationship to indicate that `1111` is following `5555`

Initially I had the following cypher statment:

```
// Try to match against existing user node, or create new
MERGE (u1:User {user_id:'t5555'})
// Try to match against existing social node, or create new
MERGE (s:Social {name:'twitter'})
// Try to match against a user who has a twitter account '1111'
MERGE (u2:User)-[:Account {name:1111}]->(s)
// Try to add account for new user 5555
MERGE (u1)-[:Account {name:'5555'}]->(s)
// Try to find `FOLLOWS` relationship
MERGE (u2)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u1)
```

But that didn't really work right. I realized that I'm matching against `user_id` while I should only be matching against twitter account names in relationships.

A more recent try is the following:

```
MERGE (u1:User)-[:ACCOUNT {name:1111}]->(s1:Social {name:'twitter'})
MERGE (u2:User)-[:ACCOUNT {name:5555}]->(s2:Social {name:'twitter'})
MERGE (u1)-[:FOLLOWS]-(u2)
```

This does add a new node for the user `u2` (though without user_id atm), but it also creates a new `Social` node. I sort of get why due to what is explained [here](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/07/31/cypher-merge-explained.html), but there they assume that there is a label on the actual node to match against.

So what would be the right way to do this? Ideally in a way that I can always use the same statement. For example that after adding the fact that `1111` is following `5555` I can also add that `2222` is following `5555` without creating any unnecessary new nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your graph model, and that's why you are facing the actual problem.

#### Let me explain the problem with your model

How can you say if User a likes User b on facebook? you can't create a relationship pointing to another relationship, if you point to the user, you'll have to specify which social account the user is liking (adding a property in the relation).

#### How to create a better graph model?

In fact, I think your mistake here is to store the account as a relationship, where you have to store it as a node.

Here is a basic drawing for a good graph model in your case:
[image: Graph Model]

Using a model like this, you can have a User related to multiple accounts, and liking other user's account (You can add a timestamp property in the `LIKE` relation if needed using timestamp() method).

Also, you can add more informations 'around accounts (twitter profile description, facebook banner uri, etc...)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. This is my first time working with neo4j, so I still have to wrap my head around it. Eventually there will also be other social networking sites, so not only Twitter, but also for example Facebook and Instagram. Should these account nodes then be independent of the actual social network, so only contain the account name and be connected to the Social node with a specific social network name, or should I then use nodes that represent the actual social networks and contain the usernames? Or should I rather put this in a separate question.

Comment: Simply create a new Account node, an link it to your user, and to the Social Network (typically your facebook Social node for a facebook account). I can open a chat room to talk about it if you need more help.

Comment: I would appreciate that. Because now I'm not completely sure about the structure other parts of the graph either.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89924/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-32629781-how-to-use-merge-or-something-else-in

Answer (score 2):

You need to set UNIQUE constraint on those properties.

e.g.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.user_id IS UNIQUE
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html

Comment: Thank you, wasn't aware of that possibility yet. However adding these new connections should be sort of independent of the user id and be solely based on the twitter id which is stored in the relationship. So I'm not completely sure whether this really helps with the current problem. However as pointed out by @Supamiu it seems that I made some mistakes with the actual structure of the network.